# Get Social Media Share/Like Count on the Site

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Is there any way to get the social media like and share count on the web page?

I am trying this for facebook, twitter, google+. For facebook it is working but for twitter and google+ I could not find any.

I tried it below way.

```css
.fa {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 5px 2px;
}

.fa:hover {
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.fa-facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

.fa-twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}

.fa-google {
  background: #dd4b39;
  color: white;
}

.fa-linkedin {
  background: #007bb5;
  color: white;
}


.fa-pinterest {
  background: #cb2027;
  color: white;
}

.fa-yahoo {
  background: #430297;
  color: white;
}
p{
 font-size:14px;
}
```

```html
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <script src="https://webcyou.github.io/social-share-count-js/js/social-share-count.js"></script>
  <title>Share Count</title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook">
 <p data-sc-fb="http://www.eventbee.com"></p>
</a>

<a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter">
 <p data-sc-tw="https://stackoverflow.com"></p>
</a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter">
 <p data-sc-tw="https://draxe.com/emotions-lower-inflammation.com"></p>
</a>
<a href="#" class="fa fa-google">
 <p data-sc-gp="http://www.webcyou.com"></p>
</a>

<a href="#" class="fa fa-pinterest">
 <p data-sc-pr="https://www.google.com/"></p>
</a>

<a href="#" class="fa fa-linkedin">
 <p data-sc-ln="https://www.yahoo.com/"></p>
</a>

</body>
</html>
```

**Here tweets count are coming for the stackoverflow.com but not for https://draxe.com/emotions-lower-inflammation/**

PS - I found that twitter and google+ has stopped the api but should there be some third party apis for those?

Answer (score 0):

You can try using
https://www.sharedcount.com

They provide API for tracking likes and shares in different social media sites.

Comment: I think it is paid. Is there any free alternative?

Comment: https://github.com/heiseonline/shariff maybe this is an option? As i know this shows a share button with counter.

Comment: I think they provide about 10K free API calls everyday

Comment: {"StumbleUpon":1,"Pinterest":9,"LinkedIn":3744,"Facebook":{"total_count":168,"comment_count":53,"reaction_count":14,"share_count":101,"comment_plugin_count":0}}

I tried this but Google+ and twitter is not there.